# ZFS mirror bootable? (to boot from it in case the other fails)

Tags: freebsd, hard-disk, zfs, bootable, mirror

I'm looking to have a ZFS mirror on my small fileserver, that's essentially one "mobile workstation" with two 2.5" drive bays, DVD drive, USB3, all the slots, and ports you can imagine, and I got a gaming laptop now, so I decided to make it a fileserver, hopefully have it run services like NextCloud, and things like that, so obviously I would want to have a mirror, but I would want it to be bootable so I can just switch the boot device, and be back online...

If I just set the device as a mirror, it's not going to be swappable as-is, right?  It's just going to dump ZFS data right onto the bare drive, right?  I want it to copy the data over, but I'd like the drives to be "cold-swappable", as I exlained, so just setting the mirror in `zfs` probably isn't going to do what I want: like if one fails, I can just boot off the other one, until I can find another drive, and switch the mirror to primary, and repeat this for the replacement drive...

But how do I make it bootable?  I guess I just do it the the same you you prepare any other drive to be bootable?  Probably replicate the filesystem with `gpart` and install bootcode with `gpart bootcode` command?  Could I just `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4k count=[2048 {or something)]`?

Also does the drive have to be exactly similar capacity or larger, or let's say it's a few sectors short, is it going to work?

I don't have experience with mirrors at all, so if anyone could give me the big lines of what I should, do, and the details, pitfalls, and heads-up, that would be very much appreciated.

The fileserver needs a good blast of compressed air, and I'm thinking of putting in the new hard drive at the same time...

Thanks in advance for your time, and your help,

Comment: There are some "root on ZFS" pages at the FreeBSD wiki, they are out-of-date, but they may be enough to illustrate how it works. The standard installer will create a ZFS mirror across two physical drives and places the boot code on both, so they can be used either way around. How you boot the system with just one plugged in, I don't know, you will have to experiment.

Comment: Well I'm going to wait until I have either managed to get the stuff out of the drive with BitLocker on it, it's not bootable, but if I put it in a USB enclosure I might be able to mount it on my Windows 10 machine, and free-up that drive...  I'm thinking I'm just going to use geli, gpart, and essentially just get the drive the same as the other one, and use the resulting device node to create a mirror on...  Guess I'll learn a lot in the experience, but I'm also hoping someone might come around with a few heads-up, and tricks about it meanwhile...  It's no emergency, jusr a planned thing rn...

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were planning a fresh install. Migrating an existing disk, without losing its data, from a non-mirror configuration into a mirror configuration by adding another disk is probably unrealistic.

Comment: This is how it's done on Solaris:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gkdep/index.html  You need to install whatever bootloader FreeBSD uses on the second disk in such a way that it's set to use that second disk as its OS root drive.  FWIW, this is one reason why hardware RAID is often used for boot drives - it's a lot simpler to do the OS install, and if an OS update changes the boot parameters you don't have to remember to update the second drive's boot settings.

Comment: I strongly recommend repeatedly practising the install in a VM with two (or more) virtual drives.  Keep practising until you understand how it works.  Also practise various failures (e.g. disabling/removing a drive from the VM, or writing garbage over random sectors of one of the virtual drives with dd and then running scrub) - this will let you see how the system responds and also practise recovery methods.   As for booting, you'll need the boot-loader installed on BOTH drives so that the system will still boot in degraded mode even if one drive dies.  This is true for real hardware and VMs.